# How to separate object in an imported model from sketchup to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, sketchup

I have imported the house model from SketchUp to unity for my AR project. The exporting process went fine but when I tried to apply the texture on each part of the house, it just applied for the whole house. I want to know if there's a way to separate each part of the model so that I can apply the texture for each part not the whole house.

Here is my house model after export. The textures are in the separate folder.

[image]

As you can see, the door, windows, floors are all connected.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole model most likely came with a single material applied to each and every part of the model.
Since that material is shared, if you apply something to it, it gets applied to all of them.

You need to create more material instances in your project and apply to each part.
Then modifying the material will only affect the part where it is used.

Comment: I'm not sure is it the export problem or it's the creating model problem. Do you have any suggestion about that?

Comment: You could check if Sketchup allows for material export (I'd say it should) or you'd have to set the material manually but check first about exporting material properly.

Comment: Oh I think it's the problem when I export it. I tried clicking on other options and it seems to work better even though it doesn't look exactly the same. Thanks a lot!